# how to use delete the query through csv bulk import in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Description      articleno       description    size
    0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7
    10125          500845-400     nikeshoes       8
    0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7
    0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7
    1254         125456-700       nikeshoes      12
```

I am importing csv :

```
barcode     articleno       Description      size
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7 
 10125         500845-400     nikeshoes        8
```

**OUTPUT** : balace stocks

```
barcode     articleno       Description      size
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7 
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7 
  1254         125456-700     nikeshoes        12
```

Comment: Do not want us to write code for you. Just hint, compare by barcode(I think it is unique), and remove matched ones while importing

Comment: id i delete using barcode  delete from table where barcode = "0101010"   then i am using sql select query to display table it will display now only barcode 10125 , 1254

Comment: Here's a general plan: create a temporary table, insert the CSV into that temporary table via a LOAD DATA INFILE command, delete rows from your permanent table that match those of the temporary table on the basis of barcode and size (make sure to use a LIMIT 1 clause), and drop the temporary table. Now you give it the old college try.

Comment: DELETE FROM `contacts` WHERE articleno = '500845-400' AND size = '7' LIMIT 1   this way  before i dint gave limit  now its fine thanks for all